# Reprojecting PostgreSQL/PostGIS data as it streams in?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I have a postgres/postgis database.

I would like to reproject those data coming to me in 4326 to 32736.

For those tables with lat long info in wgs84 (4326) I have set the geom to 4326. Then I have copied the table and used transform to reproject to 32736.

```
CREATE TABLE household.a_household_utm AS SELECT * FROM household.a_household;

ALTER TABLE household.a_household_utm 
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point,32736) USING ST_Transform(geom,32736);
```

This means that I will have to repeat this every time new data comes in if I want the dataset to be in 32736.

What is the best practice approach for re-projecting all data that is streaming in. Is a trigger function the best? I would re-project each new record on insert/update? I am not sure how I would do this.

1. You would set the projection of that record imported using the lat/long fields
2. then reproject it using ST_TRANSFORM

something like?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hh_geom_lon_lat() RETURNS trigger AS  
$$
BEGIN  
  NEW.geom = ST_Transform(
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || NEW.longitude || ' ' || NEW.latitude || ')', 4326),
  32736);
  RETURN NEW;
END;  
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

how would you set the table projection initially?

Comment: How are you inserting the data. There is nothing wrong with triggers, but you could also do the transform directly as part of the insert. Note, you can use ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(x,y), srid) instead of ST_GeomFromText with text concatenation. Nothing wrong with what you have done, but it avoids all the ||.